# Nullpointerexception in Object2ObjectOpenHashMap put method

Tags: java, hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce

I have a problem with Object2ObjectOpenHashMap, when i use put method java give me this exception "NullPointerException".

This is the code:

```
private Object2ObjectOpenHashMap level1 = new Object2ObjectOpenHashMap();
private Object2ObjectOpenHashMap level0 = new Object2ObjectOpenHashMap();
```

```
    public void map(Object ke, Text val, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        int numberAttributes = conf.getInt("numberAttributes", 0);
        String jsoncombinationlevel0 = conf.get("combinationlevel0");
        String jsonopenlevel0 = conf.get("openlevel0");
        String jsoncombinationlevel1 = conf.get("combinationlevel1");

        ArrayList<OpenBitSet> open1ArrayList = new Gson().fromJson(val.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<OpenBitSet>>(){}.getType());
        ArrayList<OpenBitSet> open0ArrayList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonopenlevel0.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<OpenBitSet>>(){}.getType());
        ArrayList<CombinationHelper> chLevel0 = new Gson().fromJson(jsoncombinationlevel0.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<CombinationHelper>>(){}.getType());   
        ArrayList<CombinationHelper> chLevel1 = new Gson().fromJson(jsoncombinationlevel1.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<CombinationHelper>>(){}.getType());   

        //ricostruisco level1
        int i=0;
        for(OpenBitSet x : open1ArrayList) {
            level1.put(x, chLevel1.get(i)); 
            i++;

        }
    //other stuff
    .
    .
    .}
```

So, when the code arrive in the for, and i use put method java give me that exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at hadoop.InitializeCplusForLevelMapReduce$MapperInitializeCplusForLevel.map(InitializeCplusForLevelMapReduce.java:78)
```

where line 78 is

```
level1.put(x, chLevel1.get(i));
```

I don't know why, it seems correct, I want create level1, and for each openBitSet in relative arraylist I wanna put it in level1 with the relative combinationHelper. Ifound only put methd, I've tried other method but it's the same things, same exception.

Comment: Object2ObjectOpenHashMap is not part of Hadoop or Java, so where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

I think `chLevel1` is being null because the string couldn't be parsed to your object class

Also, you should only do `new Gson()` once, preferably as a static field

Comment: I found the error, it happen beacause i should do level1.put((OpenBitSet) x, chLevel1.get(i)); , with the cast to OpenBitSet. But I'dont understand why, x is already an OpenBitSet.

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast, but you can't put null keys into a HashMap